# Two route variables with the same start URL in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8, laravel-controller

Is possible have two variables and same start of URL?
I mean `'turnaje/{tournament}'` and `'turnaje/{region}'`.

```
Route::get('/turnaje', [TournamentController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/turnaje/pridat', [TournamentController::class, 'create'])
    ->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/turnaj/{tournament}', [TournamentController::class, 'show']);
Route::get('/turnaje/{region}', [TournamentController::class, 'show_region']);

Route::resource('turnaje', TournamentController::class)
    ->parameters(['tournaments' => 'tournaments:slug'])
    ->except(['index', 'show', 'choose', 'create'])
    ->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: No, you can't have the same pattern for two routes. How would the router know which of the two to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible because after Laravel is confused, doesnt know what do zou want.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by two ways

If param can be resolved by https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints (one has numerical id, second has slug, etc.)

Or create shared controller thats resolve by required param

- find in regions
- if not found, find in tournaments
- cannot use implicit binding, must use string

But I recommend splitting it exactly by route `/{region}/turnaje`